# undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im getting this error after updating a has_one field

```
undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class
```

This is the code, on after_sign_up of Devise

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
protected

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
@dash = Dashboard.create(name: "David")
@user = current_user
@user.dashboard_id = @dash.id
@user.save
end
end
```

The code works, but give the error in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading. `after_sign_up_path_for` expects you to return a path. The last statement in your method (`@user.save`) returns a boolean. The error should disappear if you add a (return) statement at the end of your method to provide the path.